# vs2012: inherit/reference user defined property sheets?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a decent handful of property sheet files (.props), here is a short example:

- global.props
- x86.props
- x64.props
- app.props
- lib.props

It's very tedious to assign all of the correct property sheets to the correct configurations. What I'd like to do is create, for example, app_x86.props which simply references global.props, x86.props, app.props, so that I only have to assign one property sheet to each project configuration.

Is there any way to do this kind of referencing of property sheets?

Comment: In VS2010 I see no way to do this. Whould be great feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfectly possible with the UI: go to `View->Property Manager`, add a new property sheet, then add other property sheets to that sheet (right-click the base sheet, `Add new Project Property Sheet`, just like for adding sheets to the project). You will see VS indents them to show they are imported into another sheet. The created property sheet will of course also use the Import element as in your answer.

Comment: I will upvote this twice.   How did you discover it?

Comment: @javaLover don't recall that, it's years ago. I assume I saw 'Property Manager'  and looked up the documentation and after that I realized it's a very convenient feature (both the ui and the hierarchy of props files)

Comment: Unbelievable, I have skimmed around https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx  a few days, still not find anything cool like this.   .....  What "document" do you usually read?  The Microsoft website? A book?  Your company's secret document?

Comment: @javaLover combination of search, msdn then followed by actually trying it out, just reading stuff usually doesn't get me far. In this case probably I searched for "visual studio property manager" and back then landed on a page like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173410(v=vs.90).aspx. Currently first hit for this search is actually the page you show and under second paragraph 'Build configurations' it has a link to 'Creating reusable property configurations' and there it explains a bunch of stuff about Property Manager.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. I don't think there's a way to do it via the VS GUI, but if you open the .props file in a text editor, within the  tag you can do:

- `<Import Project="other.props" />`

and this will do what I was looking for.

However, if you edit the property sheet using the VS GUI, when the file is saved it will no longer contain the import reference

Comment: to work around the save issue I've created special "final" .props files that *only* include other props files - this way there's nothing in them that I would want to edit.